# Pass Latitude and Longitude to a javascript function and get a view from the google map

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-maps

I'm implementing a PHP website using weather data. I want to know how to pass latitude and longitude values from an HTML element with a JavaScript `onClick` event. I have used this code to get Google maps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
   <style type="text/css">
     html { height: 100% }
     body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
     #map_canvas { height: 100% }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key*****************&sensor=true"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
         var myOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
         zoom: 8,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p onClick="initialize()">Search</p>
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, the latitude and longitude coordinates are inside the JavaScript function. But, I want the HTML paragraph tag like:

```
<p onClick=".....">6.234235, 34.234345</p>
```

And I want to pass above values as a URl like:

```
https://www.google.lk/maps/@[lat],[long]
```

Does anyone know how to pass a URL like this to the above function?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want a google api that accepts lat long in the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way could be gathering the coords from the `<p>` node and parse them to the Google Maps Initialize function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
   <style type="text/css">
     html { height: 100% }
     body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
     #map_canvas { height: 100% }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key*****************&sensor=true"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
         var coords = document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML.split(",");
         var lat = coords[0];
         var lng = coords[1];

         var myOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
         zoom: 8,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

       var myMarkerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: myMarkerLatlng,
           map: map,
           title: 'Hello World!'
       });
    }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p onClick="initialize()">Search</p>
     <p id="coords" onClick="initialize()">6.234235, 34.234345</p>
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine.. I want to place a marker for the google map. Is it possible here to do that?

Comment: Edited with a marker, you can check more info at Google Maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: appreciate your help! Another small question; instead of embedding it to the same page, how to open the Google map with the given coordinates in a new window?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but I stumbled on this while searching my own answer. I found my solution based on what I learned here:

> In Markup:

```
<div id="map" data-lat="<?php echo $locationInfo[0]['lat']; ?>" data-lon="<?php echo $locationInfo[0]['lng']; ?>"></div>
```

> In Javascript:

```
var themap = document.getElementById('map');

    //console.log('lat: ' +themap.dataset.lat);
    //console.log('lon: ' +themap.dataset.lon);
    var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(themap.dataset.lat, themap.dataset.lon),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

I haven't tested it in your code, but this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values from the p tag, and an ID to it and include this in your initialize() function:

```
var latLng = document.getElementById('yourId').innerHTML.split[', '];
    var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latLng[0], latLng[1]),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

If you've got multiple p tags with different locations that users can click, set up an event listener and call getSource() on the event object instead of document.getElementById().